# Modify mapStateToProps for universal access

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have started working with redux in react native and got a problem with the mapStateToProps-function. I want to make the function universal for all my variables from my store, that I don't have to update every single variable in the mapStateToProps-function.

When I click on a button to update a variable for example this.props.secondDishAmount I have to update all the other variable too because otherwise the variables become undefined.

Is there a way to change the mapStateToProps-function to make it universal?

Thanks in advance!

```
class Restaurant extends React.Component {

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        firstDishAmount: state.firstDishAmount,
        secondDishAmount: state.secondDishAmount
    }
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        increaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREASE_COUNTER' }),
        decreaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREASE_COUNTER' }),
        addFirstDishToCart: () => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_FIRST_DISH_TO_CART' }),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Restaurant);
```

...

```
const initialState = {
    firstDishAmount: 0,
    secondDishAmount: 0,
    thirdDishAmount: 0,
    totalPrice: 0,
    firstDishPrice: 5.9,
    secondDishPrice: 12.6,
    thirdDishPrice: 11.9,
}
const shoppingBagItems = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log(state.firstDishAmount, state.secondDishAmount, state.totalPrice)
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREASE_COUNTER':
            return {
                firstDishAmount: state.firstDishAmount + 1,
                secondDishAmount: state.secondDishAmount,
                totalPrice: state.totalPrice,
                firstDishPrice: state.firstDishPrice
            }
        case 'DECREASE_COUNTER':
            return {
                firstDishAmount: state.firstDishAmount - 1,
                secondDishAmount: state.secondDishAmount,
                totalPrice: state.totalPrice,
                firstDishPrice: state.firstDishPrice

            }
        case 'ADD_FIRST_DISH_TO_CART':
            return {
                totalPrice: state.totalPrice + state.firstDishAmount * state.firstDishPrice,
                firstDishAmount: 0,
                secondDishAmount: state.secondDishAmount,
                firstDishPrice: state.firstDishPrice

            }
    }
    return state
}

export default shoppingBagItems;
```

...

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import shoppingBagItems from '../reducers/shoppingBagItems';


export default store = createStore(shoppingBagItems)
```

Comment: You can do that by exporting the same as a module and then import anywhere.

Comment: How would this work @SaachiTech?

Comment: I misunderstand your question and seems what markerikson answered is correct in your case.

Answer (score 2):

There's several things you should do to improve this code:

- First, you should switch to using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which is [our recommended approach for writing Redux logic](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-redux-toolkit-for-writing-redux-logic).
- *If* you were going to write the reducers "by hand", you should use the JS object spread operator to spread the existing state fields in each case:

```js
        case 'DECREASE_COUNTER':
            return {
                ...state,
                firstDishAmount: state.firstDishAmount - 1,
            }
```

- However, by using Redux Toolkit, you can write "mutating" code that is actually turned into a safe immutable update:

```js
const shoppingBagSlice = createSlice({
  name: "shoppingBag",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    decreaseCounter(state, action) {
      // Can safely "mutate" the existing state inside of `createSlice`
      state.firstDishAmount--;
    }

  }
})

// createSlice generates "action creators" automatically
const { decreaseCounter } = shoppingBagSlice.actions;
export default shoppingBagSlice.reducer;
```

- If you're going to use `connect` with React, you should use [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object):

```js
import { decreaseCounter } from "./shoppingBagSlice";

const mapDispatch = { decreaseCounter };

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(MyComponent);
```

- But, we also recommend using [the React-Redux hooks API instead of `connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks).

I just published a brand-new "Redux Essentials" core docs tutorial, which teaches beginners "how to use Redux, the right way", using our latest recommended tools and practices. I'd encourage you to check it out:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts